# How can I tell wget to use only 80 characters for its progressbarr when the terminal window is wider then that

Tags: shell, terminal, wget, column-width

In a terminal which is a lot wider than 80 columns `wget` uses the full width for its progress bar. How can I tell it to use only 80 characters?

In the calling shell I tried

```
export COLUMNS=80
```

and

```
stty cols 80
```

Both does not seem to affect `wget`.

PS: I use wget 1.20.3 installed via brew on macOS, but I think this will be applicable to other unix-ish environments as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `stty` bit you tried doesn't do the trick, you likely can't.

With the bar style progress meter, if standard error is a terminal, it is queried for its width, and that is used. (See [`determine_screen_width()`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git/tree/src/utils.c#n1952) in `utils.c` for how that's done). If that fails, a hard coded width of 80 is used (`DEFAULT_SCREEN_WIDTH` in `progress.c`). It doesn't check environment variables or have another way for the user to manually specify a width.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a lot!